# facing issue while trying to add auth0 into angular web application

Tags: angularjs, auth0

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('toolbar')
        .directive('toolbar',toolbar);

    function toolbar(){
        return {
            templateUrl: 'toolbar/toolbar.template.html',
            controller: toolbarController,
            controllerAs: 'toolbar'
        }
    }

    function toolbarController(auth,$localStorage,$location) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.login = login;
        vm.logout = logout;
        vm.auth = auth;

        function login() {
            auth.signin({},function(profile,token){
            $localStorage.profile = profile;
            $localStorage.id_token = token;
            $location.path('/companies');
            }, function(err){
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
        function logout() {
            delete $localStorage.profile;
            delete $localStorage.id_token;
            auth.signout();

        }
    }
})();
```

I was following auth0 video tutorials, i did exactly what was told in the video still i am facing this issue:

this above code is of a directive. and when i click from the html

```
angular.js:13708 TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseOptions' of undefined
    at getInnerLibraryConfigField (auth0-angular-4.js:240)
    at Object.auth.signin (auth0-angular-4.js:604)
    at toolbarController.login (toolbar.directive.js:23)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14605), <anonymous>:4:270)
    at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15694)
    at callback (angular.js:25622)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17444)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17544)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:25627)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (angular.js:3488)
```

I am not good in angular js please help
tutorials:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WiD3V_gmzA8

please help guys!

Comment: Did you init/config auth?

Comment: yes i have done that:                                                       angular.module('toolbar')
 .config(function($provide,authProvider,jwtInterceptorProvider){

  authProvider.init({
   domain: 'utkarsh-auth.eu.auth0.com',
   clientID: 'I1py7iUUKm5nff2aZ1x8KN3yBThJRLTF'
  });
 })